# Can't open Java Preferences with Oracle Java 7 installed

Tags: macos, java

I have both Oracle Java 7 and Apple Java 6 installed. Apple Java 6 is disabled in Java Preferences.

Now, when I try to launch Java Preferences I get a "Cannot launch "Java Preferences - No compatible version of Java 1.5+ is available." error:

[image: Java Preferences error]

This is the output of `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    1.7.0_05, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Besides the (Oracle) `1.7.0.jdk` folder,  `/System/Library/Java` also contains a `1.6.0_31-b04-413.jdk` folder.

Comment: With more recent distributions of Java from Apple and Oracle, the question is no longer applicable; an update from Apple explicitly removes Java Preferences from the Utilities folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by installing [Java for OS X 2012-004](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1515) from Apple.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1515 is not found, error 404.

Answer (score 2):

Java for OS X 2012-004 isn’t available any longer. But [2012-005](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) solved the issue for me.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572 no longer refers to 2012-005. DL1572 is currently for Java for OS X 2013-003.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Apple's Java package.  Currently, the latest version is [2013-001](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572)

Comment: [Java for OS X 2012-006 removed Java Preferences](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5493), readers should not expect Apple's more recent distribution to reinstall the app.