# Minecraft Immediately Crashes On Launchup

Tags: macos, java

I'm running Mavericks 10.9.5.
This is my java version:

[image: http://prntscr.com/7s9xnw]

Whenever I started Minecraft up, it would immediately crash.

I tried:

- Reinstalling Minecraft
- Deleting the minecraft folder in Application Support
- Reinstalling Java

Hints for the problem:

- Downloaded the most recent Java. Version 8 Update 45.
- Ran this command in terminal:

---

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/java-1.6
```

- Ran this command in terminal:

---

```
sudo ln -s '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Content­s/Home/bin/java' /usr/bin/java
```

I was having troubles with running a plugin, so I thought it was my java. After I did all of that, java wouldn't work at all. I tried to enter "java -version" in terminal, and it would say "unknown command".

After that happened, I went to Apple Java, and installed the most recent build, found here: https://support.apple.com/downloads/java

I installed "Java for OS X 2015-001 Beta.

After that, I could type in "java -version" with no problem. After I restarted my computer, Minecraft wouldn't launch. When I try to run my own server, it starts up, and then it fails and crashes.

Note: Java Control Panel also crashes on launch.

Comment: Anyone? Really need help!

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88110/make-minecraft-or-java-preferences-app-run-on-java-7?rq=1 & links

Answer (score 1):

Do you have mods? Delete those first then try. To delete them go into application support then minecraft then mods and delete them.

Answer (score -1):

I think your java version is not supported by minecraft version.

try upgrading jdk

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to Delete Minecraft on your computer and reinstalling it?
(Not sure if you need to buy it again)